# How to check out successfully with Braintree::Transaction.sale without hard coded values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, payment, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I was able to make a successful check out with a hard coded amount i.e:

```
def checkout
    nonce = params["payment_method_nonce"]

    if current_user.braintree_id?
        customer = Braintree::Customer.find(current_user.braintree_id)
    else
        @result = Braintree::Customer.create(
            email: current_user.email,
            payment_method_nonce: params[:payment_method_nonce]
          )
          customer = result.customer
          current_user.update(braintree_id: customer.id)
end

     @result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
      amount: **"10.00"**,
      payment_method_nonce: nonce
    )

    if @result.success? 
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "You have successfully checked out"
    else
        flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong while processing your transaction"
        render :new
    end
end
```

Let's say I want a current_user to be able to purchase access to my portfolio for a specific "price" which has been stored inside my rails database. Is there a way to set the amount by pulling it from an a object's attributes from the database i.e: "<=@portofolio_item.price>" ?? I've tried multiple attempts and didn't have any lucks. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation of the Rails framework:

[ActiveRecord Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html)

You need to map a new field from the table the PortfolioItems model. In order to do that you first need to add that field to the table by creating a migration, I recommend using a decimal, because floats can cause issues if you are limiting the ammount after the comma.

Each portfolio_item should have it's priced stored as decimal with a scale of two:

```
t.decimal :price, scale: 2, precision: 5
```

This will allow the item to have a price associated with it and will make the method: `@portfolio_item.price` available.

Then you just need to replace in your controller:

```
 @result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
      amount: **"10.00"**,
      payment_method_nonce: nonce
    )
```

with:

```
 @result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
      amount: @portfolio_item.price,
      payment_method_nonce: nonce
    )
```

Comment: "Each portfolio_item should have it's priced stored as decimal with a scale of two, This will allow the item to have a price associated with it and will make the method: @portfolio_item.price available." - Why is this, where is it documented, and how would anyone ever come to know this? is it just a rails thing that makes that particular column type available as a price method?

Comment: Updated answer, sorry about the lack of sources.